Selenium / chromedriver problem status code: 127
I'm in the proccess of completing the final project for CS50P and I want to use Selenium to scrape data from web (seems to be called dynamic content, which is why I saw I couldn't use requests). Note: I'm using VS studio in the cloud via the cs50.dev
Selenium is installed via pip install.
I think there's a few problems with the chrome driver:

I don't have the right version. My chrome version is Version 129.0.6668.71 yet I can only find Version 129.0.6668.70 online to download. Does the version have to match correctly? If so, how does one find the right chrome driver when the official website does not have it available to download?

If "1" is not an issue, well, I simply put the chromedriver.exe into the project folder (check picture below):



Yet, when I try to run this code:
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

which should simply open a chrome tab, I'm getting an error message as follows:

Any ideas as to how I can go about this?
Here's the full window view:
enter image description here
Thanks.
I tried to do this even locally in VS Code. While I get no error, the chrome tab doesn't open at all when I run the code.


Only major version has to match.  So you're good.  V29 for Chrome and Chromedriver.  2) Looks like the driver crashed.  You have "chromedriver.exe" in your screenshot of the project... I think that's for Windows, but the exception you show is for Linux chromedriver.  (seems like the built-in driver manager downloaded that)  What OS are you running?  Try running chromedriver listed in your exception to see what sort of errors it is throwing.


Also check to be sure you've added all Selenium's dependencies/libs to your project.

Hi,
Thanks for the reply.
So I ran downloaded the linux driver and placed it in the folder instead of the windows version. Then I ran the exception listed in the terminal, and this is what I get:
/home/ubuntu/.cache/selenium/chromedriver/linux64/129.0.6668.70/chromedriver: error while loading shared libraries: libnss3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

as is, selenium will automatically download and run the correct versions (driver and browser)  You won't need to add chromedriver to your project.  You're receiving an error that implies that the driver crashed.  If you manually run that driver (from the path shown in your exception) it should give you more details on why it crashed.  Probably permissions issue or missing dependencies... or Chrome browser isn't working or hasn't been run yet.  You should also try to launch Chrome and see if that's working.

You should also include your full driver initialization code.  Is it more than just "driver = webdriver.Chrome()"?

Excuse my knowledge here. So the reason I'm using the chrome driver is so, I can access a specific URL: for example:
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = "https://www.google.com/"
driver.get(url)
Yet even in this case I still get the 127 status code, and then when I run that linux version the libnss3.so doesn't exist for some reason.

Edit: I installed the libnss3.so and tried running again, now I receive another error xD
Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
(session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
(The process started from chrome location /home/ubuntu/.cache/selenium/chrome/linux64/129.0.6668.70/chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

go ahead and try to run Chrome.  Does it launch?  (Sometimes just an initial run will help as it will create initial directories.)  Also, what is the OS here?  Does it have a display/GUI?

I'm actually in chrome itself running this from cs50.dev space. The OS is Windows 11 Home.
I've included a picture at the top for context.

What OS is the code actually running on?

Linux codespaces-d2b754 6.8.0-1014-azure #16~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 15 21:31:41 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Be sure to set driver options to run headless, and possible use disable-gpu flag as well... now that I see the screenshot, I'm not sure you'll be able to run Selenium from that environment.  You should run it on your own machine/IDE.

I guess so. The only tradeoff there would be that I wouldn't necessarily be able to submit the final project via their command-line tool, but I'll find a workaround to that. Nevertheless, thank you for the clarification!

you might search here for "Selenium codespaces"
